# Setting list of fields to field mapping of spatial join using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, spatial-join, field-mapping

I try to code spatial join tool and delete some fields in the result. to delete the fields i list the fields of source layer and the result layer then use the list of differences in the two list and  usedelete field management tool.it's working but not good solution.If i can set the Spatial Join field mapping to remain the source layer fields and only the "Distance_To_Next" field of the join layer, i get rid of some codes and iterates but don't know how to set the field mapping in the code.

[Scripting spatial join in ArcPy to set field attribute in field mapping object?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/150299) is the only result that i could find in the stack but not my answer.

```
import arcpy
arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis("Point1", "point2","JoinResult","JOIN_ONE_TO_ONE","#","#","INTERSECT")
listfields1 = [fraft.name for fraft in arcpy.ListFields("Point1")]
listfields2 = [fraftv.name for fraftv in arcpy.ListFields("JoinResult")]
diff_fields = [i for i in listfields2 if not i in listfields1]
for field in diff_fields:
    if field != "Distance_To_Next":
        arcpy.DeleteField_management("JoinResult",field)
```

Comment: You will need to use a `FieldMappings` object like in the answer to the other question.  I recommend checking its documentation and try some of its samples before trying to apply it to your own situation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To manipulate the fields, their order, names, and other properties it is necessary to use the [`arcpy.FieldMappings()`](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-classes/fieldmappings.htm) class. It is not very easy to get to know them and start using, so I've added extra comments to help you understand the workflow.

In this example, I am doing spatial join transferring just two fields from counties to cities.

```
import arcpy

cities = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.4\TemplateData\TemplateData.gdb\USA\cities'
counties = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.4\TemplateData\TemplateData.gdb\USA\counties'

#constructing an instance of <FieldMappings object>
fms = arcpy.FieldMappings()

#loading all field objects from counties into the <FieldMappings object>
fms.addTable(counties)

fields_sequence = ['CNTY_FIPS','CNTY_NAME']
#remove fieldmaps for those fields that are not needed in the output joined fc
fields_to_delete = [f.name for f in fms.fields if f.name not in fields_sequence]
for field in fields_to_delete:
    fms.removeFieldMap(fms.findFieldMapIndex(field))

#currently field mappings from counties have just two fields we have left
#[f.name for f in fms.fields] [u'NAME', u'CNTY_FIPS']

#now need to create a new fms and loat all fields from cities fc
#compiling output fms - all fields from cities
fms_out = arcpy.FieldMappings()
fms_out.addTable(cities)

# we need to add those two fields from counties
for field in fields_sequence:
    mapping_index = fms.findFieldMapIndex(field)
    field_map = fms.fieldMappings[mapping_index]
    fms_out.addFieldMap(field_map)

#[f.name for f in fms_out.fields] [all cities fields ] + [u'CNTY_FIPS',u'CNTY_NAME']

arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis(target_features=cities, join_features=counties,
                          out_feature_class=r'C:\ArcGIS\scratch.gdb\resJoin',
                          join_operation='JOIN_ONE_TO_ONE',join_type='KEEP_ALL',
                          field_mapping=fms_out,match_option='WITHIN',
                          search_radius=None,distance_field_name=None)
```

Comment: Alex How about performance consideration? Is your code has better performance ?

Comment: @wetland, do we have anything to compare with? :)